# UILocalNotification not being fired when updating device time?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

In my app I'm scheduling `UILocalNotification`.

When I change my device time (via Settings), The UILocalNotifications do not fire consistently. Sometimes they fire, sometimes they don't.

The notifications that aren't fired, I can still see them under scheduledLocalNotifications in the UIApplication :

```
(lldb) po [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications][0]
<UIConcreteLocalNotification: 0x17434cb80>{
fire date = Saturday, February 21, 2015 at 11:45:52 PM EST, 
time zone = America/New_York (EST) offset -18000, 
repeat interval = 0, 
repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, 
next fire date = Saturday, February 21, 2015 at 11:45:52 PM EST, 
user info = {
  packageId = 66;
}}
```

And here's the `[NSDate date]` on my test device :

```
(lldb) po [NSDate date]
2015-02-24 04:51:39 +0000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The date "Saturday, February 21, 2015" has already past according to the date of your phone "2015-02-24 04:51:39 +0000" .
If you want to repeat it then you have to set the repeatInterval of the UILocalNotification which can take following values:

- NSWeekCalendarUnit
- NSWeekdayCalendarUnit
- NSWeekdayOrdinalCalendarUnit
- NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit
- NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit

Comment: I thought that notifications in the past would be fired.  From Apple's dev docs :

The fire date is interpreted according to the value specified in the timeZone property. If the specified value is nil or *is a date in the past*, the notification is delivered immediately.